# Save changes to Add-in file

Tags: excel, vba, save, add-in

I've set a routine to save my add-in before close, like this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

    If ThisWorkbook.Saved = False Then ThisWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

Still Excel prompts me with this message "Want to save your changes to (filename)?"

I'started getting this message after I started changing the isAddin property during the execution of a macro.

How to get rid of this message.

Comment: Either that message is one you have in your addin code, or its referring to another book that's open.

Comment: I haven't added this messages. What could cause this messages? Maybe I've changed something that is causing this.

Comment: Since you're using an add-in.  ThisWorkbook I believe is referencing the 'Add-In' workbook and not the host workbook.  Try changing your object reference to 'ActiveWorkbook' and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  If ThisWorkbook.Saved = False Then ThisWorkbook.Save
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True

  thisworkbook.close

End Sub
```

It is also recommended to add an on error statement to set Application.DisplayAlerts back to true

Answer (score 1):

See if this works

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  If ThisWorkbook.Saved = False Then ThisWorkbook.Save
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I still get the message.